# Linq, Lambda and nullable DateTime combination question 

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

### I have a Schedule class:

```
public class Schedule
{

 .....

 public DateTime? StartDate{get;set;}
 public DateTime? EndDate{get;set;}

 ....

}
```

---

I would like to get the list of started Schedule objects from an IEnumerable list in the optimal way using **linq** or **lambda**.

---

**NOTE:** An empty date value means infinity here. However, unspecified schedule period (empty start and end dates) means schedule is not started ..

Comment: WHat do you mean by "optimal way" ?

Comment: One statement and less processing is perfect ..

Comment: @Akram Shahda: mmh, sorry, not clear to me can you give a numeric example ?

Comment: My proposed solution can of course be merged into a single statement. But I prefer readable solutions. ;-)

Comment: Take it easy guys .. If I knew how the optimal solution would be I wont ask for it ..

Comment: The requirement to use LINQ or lamda is quite odd, care to elaborate on why it is there? Are you just curious or is there some deeper reason?

Comment: @Akram: Ah sorry, my mistake I got it, you just need the started schedules in a "optimal way" in term of code lines and processing time. Initially, I read the question like: I need the "started optimal schedules" :D

Comment: @svick: I have data that need to be processed ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
schedules.Where(s => s.StartDate < DateTime.Now
                     || (s.StartDate == null && s.EndDate != null));
```

This assumes you actually want what you said – all started schedules, including those that already ended.

Also, you might want to change the way you represent unspecified schedule period, probably by adding a `bool` for that. If `null` means infinity, it should always mean infinity.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsStarted(Schedule schedule) {
   // Assuming that ended schedules should be excluded
   return schedule.StartDate != null && schedule.StartDate > DateTime.Now
       && (schedule.EndDate==null || schedule.EndDate < Datetime.Now);
}

items.Where(IsStarted);
```

If possible, it would not be the worst idea, to make IsStarted a property of your Schedule class. In that case you would have to use:

```
items.Where(i => i.IsStarted);
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense, it is always false, because you could rewrite it as `(StartDate != null && StartDate == null) || (StartDate > Now && StartDate < Now)`.

Comment: I just fixed it. The second part of the boolean expression should compare to EndDate of course.

Comment: @Akram, while this code is wrong, it should not generate an exception. What exception do you get?

Comment: Why will it generate an exception?

Comment: @Achim @svick: In case StartDate was null, schedule.StartDate > DateTime.Now will generate the exception I am talking about .

Comment: The first condition in the statement is schedule.StartDate!=null, so the later part will never be executed for StartDate==null!?

Comment: Sorry .. my mistake .. and that makes things easier.

Comment: @Akram, again, exactly what exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
var started =
    from s in schedules
    let startDate = s.StartDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue
    let endDate = s.EndDate ?? DateTime.MinValue
    where startDate <= DateTime.Now
    && endDate > DateTime.Now
    select s;
```

Comment: First, you missed the unspecified schedule periods constraint. And you made a mistake by assigning max DateTime value to StartDate and min DateTime value to EndDate. However, I've learned something from this code. So, thank you.